# Calculated Query to Add "CustomDescription" Column for Each ID language

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please can you help me to figure out how to create a temporary calculated field (customDescription2, customDescription3 … …) for each idLanguage I add on the table? The data displayed on the table below are from 1 table.

[image: Before & After]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I'm using mssql server

Answer (score 1):

If you know the language ids, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select substitute, barcode,
       max(case when idlanguage = 1 then customDescription end) as customDescription1,
       max(case when idlanguage = 2 then customDescription end) as customDescription2,
       max(case when idlanguage = 3 then customDescription end) as customDescription3,
       max(case when idlanguage = 4 then customDescription end) as customDescription4
from t
group by substitute, barcode;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Your solution is perfect.